# Payment Gateway Query for iphone app

Tags: iphone, xcode, payment-gateway, feasibility

I am developing one application which has use of physical ordering like restaurant food ordering.
Now i am stuck on how will i use the payment Gateway in which i heard from many sites after searching on google that Apple is rejecting the application if I  don't want to  use the InApp Purchage as it does not support for physical goods.
I don't want to use Paypal and google checkout because it is more expensive  as per my client business.

Client uses the website already for their business in which he used the third party payment gateway from www.fatcow.com which use the service of  authorize.net
1) I got another option that i can open website mobile pages in Webview and handle it from their but still  confuse if apple will reject the app.So please tell me how should i use the 3rd party payment gateway to place my order ?.
2) How can i successful make transaction and credit card processing in application is there any API or something available please provide some information.

Any help will be appreciated .
Thank You.

Comment: To my knowledge you should not use any 3rd party payment gateways to process any debit/card transactions until unless its solely meets ISO 8583/8587 protocols and PCI (Payment Card Industries) standards. Any kind of hacky way, will put you in trouble.

Comment: @manoj: Add it as an answer so that i can upvote it. Its relevant.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge you should not use any 3rd party payment gateways to process any debit/card transactions until unless its solely meets ISO 8583/8587 protocols and PCI (Payment Card Industries) standards. Any kind of hacky way, will put you in trouble.

Answer (score 0):

nProb,you can use your existing support to make transactions but change you want to made is ask the web team to give you some API's which will carry the transaction process ,

For example , Web Team give a web service - contains all parameters [cost,creditcard etc] ,

then you pass these values from your app with form ui , the the web service will perform transaction & make to return status to your app by json or xml to intimate users that it is a successfull transaction.

Apple will never reject your app , as we have approved 5 similiar payment based apps.

Hope this helps!

Comment: can you just provide me one of your app doing same as you said above , i am not crosschecking , i just wanted to know how you have handled that fronm UI prospective .Please  give me name of one app so that i can just go through it and we can proceed further.Thanks a lot for inputs..

Comment: @mrugen : check bartab & others cp apps like livingsocial & groupon apps

Comment: In your application have you used secure information functionality if yes , How have you done that or tutorial will be helpful if u can provide me some link or tutorial for secure connection. And Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: @mrugen : Yes more important ,all your payment api should be ssl supportive - https://....

Comment: where is the link or tutorial can you provide me the same for using secure conncetion ..